# Faster multi-scope Rails query with sum and count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, where-clause

I have an `Event` model which `has_many :bookings`. My `Booking` modal has the following scopes:

```
scope :confirmed_or_pending, -> { where(confirmed: true).or(where(pending: true)).where(cancelled: false) }
scope :overlapping, -> (time, duration) { where("start_time < ? AND ? < end_time", (time + duration.minutes), time) }
```

I am running a query where, given a `time` and `duration`, I need to find out how many other (confirmed or pending) bookings overlap with this time and duration.

I want to return, in a hash format, the **number of bookings** I find as well as the **sum of all the booking `sizes`**.

I currently have this:

```
bookings = @event.bookings.confirmed_or_pending.overlapping(time.to_datetime, duration)
return {bookings: bookings.count, guests: (bookings.map{ |b| b.guest_size }.sum) }
```

This works fine but when I run it with a multitude of `time` and `duration` inputs then the query is **very slow**.

I was wondering how I could speed this up so that my code only executes a single DB query. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have indexes on those columns? Are you using mysql?

Comment: I'm using sqlite in Development and postgres in Prod yes. I have not indexed them actually. In this case what columns would need indexing?

Comment: You should always index the columns in `where`.

Comment: My suggestion is to use the same db as you have in production. It will be much easier to reproduce things. Plus sqlite is just for small, not complicated things.

Comment: Ok thanks! So just to confirm I should index `confirmed`, `pending`, `cancelled`, `start_time` and `end_time` ? Anything I can do to improve the query?

Comment: Yes start with those. Please update with `bookings.to_sql`

Comment: if you using postgres, you can always use the EXPLAIN command to see if your query is using the indexes you create. I don't see a problem on the scopes as far I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres you can use the [OVERLAPS operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-datetime.html):

```
scope :overlapping, -> (time, duration) { where("(starts_at, ends_at) OVERLAPS (?, ?)", time, time + duration.minutes) }

# consider writing this as a real class method for readiblity
# scope is just syntactic sugar for lazy one-liners
def self.overlapping(time, duration)
  where("(starts_at, ends_at) OVERLAPS (?, ?)", time, time + duration.minutes)
end
```

OVERLAPS is part of the SQL standard but far from universally supported.

Since its not supported by SQLite you need to use Postgres in testing and development which you should be doing anyways to avoid shipping bugs due to inconsistencies between the RDBMS:es.

The reason this code is so slow is most likely `bookings.map{ |b| b.guest_size }.sum` which looks like a text-book n+1 query.

One way to do this in a single query would be to select the aggregates when fetching the event:

```
event = Event.joins(:bookings)
             .where(bookings: { id: Booking.confirmed_or_pending.overlapping(time.to_datetime, duration) })
             .group(:id)
             .select(
                     'events.*', 
                     'COUNT(bookings.*) AS bookings_count',
                     'SUM(bookings.guest_size) AS guests_count'
                   )
             .find(id)
{ bookings: event.bookings_count, guests: event.guests_count }
```

Comment: If you need to further optimize the query you can replace the starts_at and ends_at columns with a single tsrange or tstzrange column which you can add a GiST index on. See http://faxon.org/2014/11/20/postgresql-indexing-overlaps-query-with-tsrange-for-scheduling

Comment: Hey @max this is awesome thanks. I would like to try your one query solution however I don't actually have a `Guest` model. The guest count should come from a sum of the `guest_size` number from all the bookings captured. How would you alter the last query to work? - I Guess it's not a left_joins ?

Comment: Use `joins(:bookings)` and `SUM(bookings.guest_size) AS guests_count `. Basically anything you select with an alias will be available as attributes on the resulting model instances.

Comment: I get a `Unsupported argument type` for `Booking` in that where clause.  Do I need a `where` or can I just call `confirmed_or_pending` after the joins?

Comment: Ah - you might need to use `where(bookings: { id: Booking.confirmed_or_pending.overlapping(time.to_datetime, duration) })`. You can't call it on the end of the chain since the recipent is Event and not Booking.

Comment: Because it looked like you're returning a hash with the counts for a single record. Remove it if you want an ActiveRecord::Relation instead.

Comment: Just replaced the `find(id)` with `find(@event.id)` and that seemed to work. Amazing thank you so much!

Comment: I still can't quite get it to do what I need to in one query. Adding `find(@event.id)` works when there are bookings present but if none I get an error obviously. If I set up a new line to check if present before finding I end up with a slow query again. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you use `left_joins` instead of `joins` it will do an outer join which will include rows from events even if there are no results in the join table. You can also use `find_by(id: @event.id)` instead of `find` if you want to avoid the ActiveRecord::RecordNotFoundException.

Comment: I added a `where(id: @event.id` inside the `where` clause to make sure I only checked this event. However if no bookings are found I am still having to do a `bookings = event.present? ? event.bookings_count : 0` for bookings and guests which (I think?) is making is slow?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230487/discussion-between-mikeholford-and-max).